# mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\kcms\a.php on line 15

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to get values from a database but it shows "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\kcms\a.php on line 15" error. Can someone help me?

```
    <?php
    //include 'functions.php';
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","Akash","kaka123");
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $student = false;
    $teacher = false;
    $office = false;
    $username = 56;
    $password = 38;
    $query= "SELECT Register_no , Password FROM student profile WHERE Register_no=$username AND Password=$password" ;
    $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
    $prnt=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if ($prnt[0]==NULL) 
    {
        $auth=0;
    }
    else
    {
        $auth=1;
        $student= true;
    }
    if ($auth==0) 
    {
        $query= "SELECT Staff_id , Password FROM staff profile WHERE Staff_id=$username AND Password=$password" ;
        $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
        $prnt=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if ($prnt[0]=NULL) 
        {
            $auth=0;
        }
        else
        {
            $auth=1;
            $teacher = true;
        }
    }    
    if ($auth==0) 
    {
        $query= "SELECT Staff_id , Password FROM office staff WHERE Staff_id=$username AND Password=$password" ;
        $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
        $prnt=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if ($prnt[0]==NULL) 
        {
            $auth=0;
        }
        else
        {
            $auth=1;
            $office = true;
        }
    }
    echo $username; 
    ?>
```

can someone please reply soon?

Comment: Your query has an error. You can do similar error checking as you are with the connection.

Comment: change: `$result = mysql_query($query, $con);` to `$result = mysql_query($query, $con) OR die(mysql_error());` and you have your solution. And you are very vulnerable for sql injections. Look into PDO or mysqli with prepared statements. And it looks like you are relying on register_globals...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Likelihood is that $username and $password are strings, and should be quoted: now stop using MySQL and start using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql_fetch_array%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+resource%2C+boolean+given

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message is actually very precise and helpful. `mysql_fetch_array()` is being called with a boolean value where a resource is expected. If you look at the documentation for `mysql_query()`, you will see that it returns `FALSE` on failure, which is a boolean. This value is stored in `$result`, which is then passed to `mysql_fetch_array()`. So, an error occurs with your SQL query. You can check the error like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Register_no , Password FROM student profile WHERE Register_no=$username AND Password=$password") or die(mysql_error());
```

That being said, you have a space between "student" and "profile" which should not be there. You probably meant to put an underscore there?

Also, please consider using MySQLi or PDO instead as the mysql_* extension is deprecated. I am merely name dropping here, so please take the time to read about these.

Comment: Please do not answer obvious questions that are that obvious that duplciates en-masse already exists which makes looking that question silly even-.

Comment: @hakre I don't see how that makes it a bad answer. That's a problem with the question, not the answer. Downvoting the answer is like saying "this answer is bad," which is clearly not the case as it solved the problem. Whether or not the question is bad is a different story.

Comment: @Andy0708: No, please move the mouse pointer over the downvote button and rest it there a moment. A tooltip should appear saying: *"This answer is not useful (click again to undo)"*. As you can see, it is about usefulness not about rightfulness. Answering duplicate questions is not useful.